# Running stored procedure without waiting for it to finish

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures

So I have this stored procedure that I run from my Spring boot application. It works and life is good.

Now I want to run it asynchronously. Just launch the process and not leave the consumer waiting for the response, but so far I haven't been able to. Both when calling it from a CompletableFuture or from a new Thread, it throws this error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: p_return_code; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OUT/INOUT parameter not available: p_return_code
```

p_return_code is the first of the output parameters. This is the code:

```
final UploadInstanceEntity finalUploadInstance = uploadInstance;
  Runnable runnable = () -> {
    System.out.println("Lambda Runnable running");
    runStoredProcedure(finalUploadInstance, fileReport);
  };

  Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
  thread.start();
```

And the function:

```
@Transactional
  private void runStoredProcedure(UploadInstanceEntity uploadInstance, FileReport fileReport) {

Map<String, Object> result = uploadInstanceRepository.fileUpload("CPI", uploadInstance.getId());
```

I added the transactional but that alone didnt fix it.

I also played around with the @Async annotation (and respective configurations), but it always ran in sync. Never in background.

Any ideas how to do this? Am I even on the right track?

Comment: What happens if you execute `runnable.run();` so it executes in the foreground - do you still get the same error?

Comment: @Bohemian No error in that case, but it runs in sequence. I don't want to have to wait for the SP to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to run in the end. As I was suspecting, the problem was that the worker thread wasn't getting a transaction. @Transactional does not support multithreading whatsoever, so if you call a method marked by it from another thread, it's like there is nothing there.

I was able to use transaction manager to force a transaction on the worker thread:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
    transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback() {
      // the code in this method runs in a transactional context
      public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
        return runStoredProcedure(finalUploadInstance, fileReport);
      }
    });

  };
  new Thread(runnable).start();
```